# Conditional formatting axis of chart.js as time scale

Tags: javascript, date, charts, momentjs, chart.js

My line chart has date values like 2016-06-01, 2016-06-01, etc on x axis. According to date range loaded dynamically from json, I want to format it depending on the number of values:

1. In case of a small amount of values (<= 60 days) I would like to show only day and month (DD-MM) like 01-06, 02-16, etc
2. In case of a big amount of values (> 60 days) I would like to show only month and year (MM-YY) like 06-16, 07-16, etc.

DD-MM can be achieved like that:

```
xAxes: [{
  type: 'time',
  unit: 'day',
  time: {
    displayFormats: {
      day: 'DD-MM',
    }
  }
}]
```

MM-YY like that:

```
xAxes: [{
  type: 'time',
  unit: 'month',
  time: {
    displayFormats: {
      day: 'MM-YY',
    }
  }
}]
```

But I'm quite lost how to combine this two and make it happen on a condition like the number of values. Is there a way to do that with ticks option of scales axis or do I have to write a new scale type?